# Woocoomerce product category count including subcategories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, count

I'm overriding `wpseo_title` to make custom titles for my Woocommerce product categories.

Part of the titles are the number of products, based on `$product_category->count`

The only problem is that count of subcategory products isn't included. It's only the products in the category itself that are counted.

Is there a way to get the product count for the category itself + its subcategories?

Answer (score 2):

`WP_Query` can be used to determine the number of posts contained within a category and its subcategories.

In the code below, set the `terms` parameter to whatever the parent category ID is. The `include_children` parameter ensures that `WP_Query` will include posts within subcategories.

We can then use `$query->post_count` to get the total number of posts in the parent category and its subcategories.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => 79, // Replace with the parent category ID
            'include_children' => true,
        ),
    ),
    'nopaging' => true,
    'fields' => 'ids',
) );

echo '<p>Total product count: <strong>' . esc_html( $query->post_count ) . '</strong></p>';
```

Comment: +1 but it probably flies way too high over the head of most readers ;) some explanation is probably needed

Comment: @MarkKaplun Good call on adding an explanation. All set!